# kill -9 command not working

Tags: kill

I am new to Ubuntu. I am using it for radius manager. When I typed

```
ps ax | grep rm
```

I got:

```
50 ?        S<     0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
1153 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/local/bin/rmconntrack
1171 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/local/bin/rmpoller
1424 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto rm
```

When I try to `kill -9 50` it does not work. I typed:

```
kill -9 50
```

Still:

```
50 ?        S<     0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
1153 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/local/bin/rmconntrack
1171 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/local/bin/rmpoller
1424 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto rm
```

It's the same; nothing killed. Can any one please help me?

Comment: I don't believe you can explicity kill something mnaged by the kernel `[acpi_thermal_pm]` is the kernel driver for power management.  As stated below, you can do that, but the kernel may just restart it

Comment: how i can at last stop it ?

Comment: In order to remove power management, you have two options, but first, add the output of `lsmod | grep thermal`

Comment: x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0

Comment: No paste the output by editing your question, I also need `lsmod | grep acpi`

Comment: @Daniel is correct, but I was making you add more information before I answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't kill Kernel Threads with userspace `kill`.

If you really want to get rid of this process, you can either remove the the thermal kernel module with `rmmod thermal`, or build a new kernel without it (if its builtin, not a module). But you shouldn't do it unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: i was installed radius manger and i want run up it 
after i typed
radiusd -X
Failed binding to authentication address * port 1812: Address already in use
/usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf[240]: Error binding to port for 0.0.0.0 port 1
i want to kill that 50 to run it up

Comment: That process has no relation at all with radiusd. The bind error means that another process is using the same udp/tcp port, probably another radiusd instance is still running.

Comment: thanks so much Daniel 
i am trying to look what the reasons for this problem .

Comment: you are right .
its working now thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be root to kill the process.
In that case add `sudo` in front of the command:

```
sudo kill -9 50
```

Comment: i was used it and i am root user

Comment: then I guess it's like eyoung100 said, it's a kernel procces that can not be killed.